# guess what 0x564c is?

Tags: linux-kernel, magic-numbers

when i read linux kernel source, i found one line says:

> #define NCP_SUPER_MAGIC         0x564c          /* Guess, what 0x564c is :-) */

(564c)16 = (22092)10 = (53114)8 = (101011001001100)2

Wolfram|Alpha tells us that 22092 = 2^2 * 3 * 7 * 263 = 43 * 2^9 + 76

ok , so do any body have any ideas of this riddle?

btw, this code appears in the file of %linux-kernel-source%/include/linux/magic.h

Comment: Or it's ASCII for 'VL' if that means anything? Who wrote that file?

Comment: @Rup: I think you're on to something, from scanning googled results, it seems to be a minimum block size for a File Allocation Table. VL possibly meaning Very Large.

Comment: @Binary Worrier: or VL means the author's name , mfukar said it was written by Volker Lendecke.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It happens to be the hex representation of the initials of Volker Lendecke, who wrote the ncpfs support for the Linux kernel. It's used as the superblock magic number in Netware 5. But basically, he's the one responsible. :-)

Comment: maybe you are approaching the answer , 0x56 is 'V' and 0x4c is 'L' -- short for name of the author , Volker Lendecke

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if it's someone's birthday...

5/6/4c = 5/6/76?

Comment: Yeah, well it's the sort of thing I might do, even if it's not actually the right answer!

Answer (score 1):

NCP stands for [NetWare Core Protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NetWare_Core_Protocol), from Novell.

[ncpfs](http://freshmeat.net/projects/ncpfs/) is an open-source NCP client implementation for Linux.